# Magento - CSS Stylesheet missing in mobile theme

Tags: css, magento

Running on Magento CE v1.7

Previously I'm using Magento Mobile HTML5 Theme for mobile displays, these are the things I've checked to ensure it works but yet it doesn't. In the source code the stylesheet is nowhere to be seen.

It was working until I tried to edit & flush all caches in Magento. After discovering CSS was not included I already reverted back the old page.xml/replaced it with the default one. I wondered what went wrong?

1) Magento Backend: System > Config > Design > Themes > Templates/Skin (Images / CSS)

Matched Expression -
iPhone|Android

Value -
mobile

2) app/design/frontend/default/mobile/layout/page.xml already included the css

`<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/iphone.css</stylesheet></action>`

3) app/design/frontend/default/mobile/template/page/html/head.phtml included the php calling:

`<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>`

Comment: Can you please show us the files in directory structure way? I think there is another page.xml in your theme folder which is overriding the default page.xml. I think so because you haven't mentioned where the above mentioned page.xml is located.

Comment: @Mr_Green I've edited the Q to include the path :)